# Strings in HTML using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python-3.x

## I am getting always No string. can someone please help me with the searching a string in the HTML file.

```
def main():
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
    raw_html = simple_get(line)
    html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
#HTML file looks good at this step.
    for line in html:
        if find in line:
            print(line)
        else:
            print("No String")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try `for find in line:`

```
def main():
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
    raw_html = simple_get(line)
    html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')
    for line in html:
        for find in line:
            print(line)
        else:
            print("No String")
```

Comment: I used the above code but somehow the output does not seems correct. eg. I used https://www.google.com/ as the url and find='Yahoo'  some how I am getting 2 lines printed in the "for find in line" loop. I scanned the output for the word Yahoo and could not find any in the output file.

Comment: Raven - My requirement is to find the words in the HTML file eg. find "web,address,test etc" in a give html file